# Jasmine test suite doesn't run

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine

I can't figure out what I've done to mess up Jasmine.

Here's a link to the repo I'm working on: 
https://github.com/bryanbeus/04-09-bloccit/tree/v0.1.3

The problem is somehow related to the files `/spec/integration/flairs_spec.js`, `/spec/integration/post_spec.js`, and probably more.

The problem can be seen when running a command like `npm test`. I get the following result:

```
04-09-bloccit@1.0.0 test /home/siddhartha/Documents/07-Temp/01-Bloc/04-09-bloccit
export NODE_ENV=test && jasmine
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

It used to be that this ERR would only occur if I had an non-compilable error somewhere in my code. (For example, a simple thing like `;` out of place, or an improper use of `this`.)

Recently, I've heard from someone else that this type of failure for Jasmine isn't normal. Usually, if there's a problem in the code, Jasmine is still supposed to say something. ?

Whatever the problem is, it is now spreading to general usage.

I'm trying to call the `server` npm module for a test with this command:

```
const server = require("../../src/server");
```

If that line is anywhere in my files, the entire Jasmine test fails in the exact same manner. (`npm ERR...` and no other details.)

If I run `npm test /spec/integration/flairs_spec.js` with that call to `server` active, the test fails in the `npm ERR...` manner.

However, if I comment out the call to `server`, then Jasmine at least runs. It returns this error:

....................

Started
F

Failures:
1) routes : flairs GET /topics/:topicId/posts/:postId/flairs/new should render a new flair form
  Message:
    Expected Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 to be null.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 to be null.
        at 
        at Request.request.get [as _callback] (/home/siddhartha/Documents/07-Temp/01-Bloc/04-09-bloccit/spec/integration/flairs_spec.js:57:21)
        at self.callback (/home/siddhartha/Documents/07-Temp/01-Bloc/04-09-bloccit/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
        at Request.emit (events.js:160:13)
        at Request.onRequestError (/home/siddhartha/Documents/07-Temp/01-Bloc/04-09-bloccit/node_modules/request/request.js:878:8)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:160:13)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:389:9)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
        at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
  Message:
    Expected undefined to contain 'New Flair'.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected undefined to contain 'New Flair'.
        at 
        at Request.request.get [as _callback] (/home/siddhartha/Documents/07-Temp/01-Bloc/04-09-bloccit/spec/integration/flairs_spec.js:58:22)
        at self.callback (/home/siddhartha/Documents/07-Temp/01-Bloc/04-09-bloccit/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
        at Request.emit (events.js:160:13)
        at Request.onRequestError (/home/siddhartha/Documents/07-Temp/01-Bloc/04-09-bloccit/node_modules/request/request.js:878:8)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:160:13)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:389:9)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
        at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.399 seconds
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

.......

So, removing the `server` call at least lets Jasmine run.

Any help on this is appreciated. Thank you for helping a novice programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the error.

Using `git diff v0.1.2..v0.1.3` I was able to see the differences between the last working branch, and the current one.

From here, I saw that in `db/src/controllers/flairController.js` I had placed this in the controller for the flair object:

```
const flairQueries = require("./db/queries.flairs.js");
```

The problem with that is that the directory isn't correct. I replaced it with this:

```
const flairQueries = require("../db/queries.flairs.js");
```

After this, the Jasmine test suite worked.

I understand that this means that the controller couldn't load properly. The full understanding of this is still elusive, so if anyone has time to try to explain, I would appreciate it. Otherwise, we can consider this question closed. Thanks!